# Javascript calendar new instance not working consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

So I am currently developing a small website which includes a hostel booking system. I have been working on an availability calendar for the site which is made with Javascript. The aim of the availability calendar to show the members the availability of the hostel on that date (which will be pulled from the database and most likely stored in a JSON array), and then to allow them to select a date range on the interface. At this stage I have the basics working but when I call the function changeMonth() to change between months, the ability to select a date range and for it to automatically update the appropriate fields.

**So The problem is that when I change the month using the "<" and ">" buttons the new instants of the calendars don't update the fields appropriately.**

```
function changeMonth(dir){
    currMonth += dir;
    if(currMonth > 11)currMonth = 6;
    if(currMonth < 6)currMonth = 11;
    $('#calendar_table').remove();
    drawMonth(currMonth, 2014);
}
```

That is the changeMonth() function; so far I only want to view the months June - November. To get a new instance of the calendar I remove the previous and draw a new one. 
The up-to-date version of the calendar is available here [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/hZssN/75/)

I am open to suggestions of alternate methods to achieve the same task I am currently doing more efficiently also, I have looking into the [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) from jQuery UI but I wasn't able to figure out a way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Sorry I'm to stupid, whats your question again?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good at expressing myself in written context. I want to figure why the calendar isn't updating correctly when changing month as seen in the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, if you redraw the calendar, the event listener on your 'a' gets lost.

**Change this:**

```
$( "a" ).on( "click", function() { //...
```

**Into this:**

```
$( "#booking_calendar" ).on( "click", "a", function() { //...
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hZssN/76/

Quoting from the jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.

Comment: I'm having the same sort of problem again, now that I'm redrawing my "<" and ">" buttons they will only ever work in the first instance.  I have tried using `$( ".next" ).on( "click", "button" function() {` but it doesn't work in this case. Do you know where I can read up on the action listner class in Javascript?
**Script:** [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZssN/78/)

Comment: Hm, I cant think of anything but the jQuery documentation to read up on. http://api.jquery.com/on/ There it says: "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()." That is, basically you need to set the event listener on a dom element which will not disappear / be redrawn. Else, you have to re-set the click event AFTER redrawing an element again.

Comment: Thanks for that, it behaves just like Java then, have to initialize the actionlistener in the paint method as it is "re-set" i suppose that makes sense.